# why does binary pair encoding (BPE) not work on binary data but only on natural languages?

Tags: nlp, compression, huggingface-transformers, binary-data

I know that BPE is used on sentences that can generate some sort of tokenization and pairings, with spare bytes being used to create such mappings. Why doesn't it work on BPE?

What would be the best guess/way to actually try to perform BPE as a form of compression of binary data?

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked with binary pair encoding so maybe got confused, but it looks very similar to [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

The dictionary is constructed similarly in the Huffman code. But rather than using characters to represent a word in a dictionary, the Huffman code assigns shorter *binary values (0 or 1)* which are based on the frequency of the repetition of the word. Most frequent words are assigned shorter *binary values*.

Huffman code is used in many compression algorithms already, like [DEFLATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflate), [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), [MP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3), [Brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli) etc.